# Fast Calculation Matrix in R

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, matrix

I have simple code, but it took 0.006 sec for one iteration using small data set, i'm afraid because i'm gonna use this on large data set. here is my code

```
d1 = matrix(0, nrow(x), num.clust)
for(i in 1:ncol(d.num){
  #For numeric attribute
  d1.temp = (w*(d.num - matrix(rep(as.numeric(num.centroid[i,]), nrows),nrow = nrows, byrow = T)))^2

  d1[,i] = rowSums(d1.temp)
}
```

and this is data frame that i used

```
> head(d.num)
x3        x4
4.842316 11.754403
6.405585 11.643502
6.590780 11.478245
6.656699 11.293404
> num.centroid
     [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 7.605837 12.59816
[2,] 7.895469 12.92275
```

w is data frame that has size with d.num. Any suggest to reduce time execution for this case ?

Comment: Hmmm... d1.temp was the longest process. Thts my concern...

Comment: What is `w`, `d1`, and `nrows` ? Please provide a complete code.

Comment: You could convert `d.num` to a matrix at the beginning (`as.matrix(d.num)`). This should increase the performance. Also note that `as.numeric` is useless in your code.

Comment: Ah ok, just seen your edit. If `w` is a data.frame I think you could also convert it to a matrix.

Comment: As already requested by @StephanLaurent, if you can provide a [complete and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) we can work on something and better help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a comparison if, as I suggested, you convert the dataframes to matrices.

```
# original code
f1 <- function(n){
  d.num <- data.frame(x3=round(rnorm(n)), x4 = round(rnorm(n)))
  w <- d.num
  num.centroid <- matrix(c(7,8,9,10), nrow=2)
  nrows = nrow(d.num)
  d1 <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow=nrows, ncol=ncol(d.num))
  for(i in 1:ncol(d.num)){
    d1.temp = (w*(d.num - matrix(rep(num.centroid[i,], nrows), 
                                 nrow = nrows, byrow = TRUE)))^2

    d1[,i] = rowSums(d1.temp)
  }
  return(d1)
}
# using as.matrix
f2 <- function(n){
  d.num <- data.frame(x3=round(rnorm(n)), x4 = round(rnorm(n)))
  w <- d.num
  d.num <- as.matrix(d.num)
  w <- as.matrix(w)
  num.centroid <- matrix(c(7,8,9,10), nrow=2)
  nrows = nrow(d.num)
  d1 <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow=nrows, ncol=ncol(d.num))
  for(i in 1:ncol(d.num)){
    d1.temp = (w*(d.num - matrix(rep(num.centroid[i,], nrows), 
                                 nrow = nrows, byrow = TRUE)))^2

    d1[,i] = rowSums(d1.temp)
  }
  return(d1)
}
```

Benchmarks:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> n <- 10
> microbenchmark(
+   code1 = f1(n),
+   code2 = f2(n),
+   times = 1000
+ )
Unit: microseconds
  expr      min        lq        mean   median       uq      max neval
 code1 1432.443 1480.8605 1628.889978 1545.789 1631.022 6229.565  1000
 code2  263.284  278.9020  313.293371  290.505  307.239 3138.880  1000
> n <- 1000
> microbenchmark(
+   code1 = f1(n),
+   code2 = f2(n),
+   times = 1000
+ )
Unit: microseconds
  expr      min       lq        mean   median        uq        max neval
 code1 1884.934 1924.873 2290.409508 1974.183 2111.8490 114038.521  1000
 code2  571.192  583.687  642.682019  601.537  637.4595   3499.891  1000
```

The second code is clearly faster.

Comment: great thank you stephane... i'm gonna add cmpfun also. hope it will be faster